# property nth-child seems not working in JSP CSS

Tags: css, jsp

I created a program that fill in a table with data of a table called usuarios but the property  nth-child seems not working
All the rows have the same color, which is  greenyellow;
. I am using Netbeans and Glassfish

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : basededatos
    Created on : 14/06/2015, 01:23:57
    Author     : fernando
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .TFtable{
                width:100%; 
                border-collapse:collapse; 
            }
            .TFtable td{ 
                padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
            }
            /* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
            .TFtable tr{
                background: red;
            }
            /*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
            .TFtable tr:nth-child(odd){ 
                background: yellow;
            }
            /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
            .TFtable tr:nth-child(even){
                background: greenyellow;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet result = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                out.println("driver registrado");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/administracion", "root", "strlen12");
                out.println("conexion exitosa");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from usuarios");
        %>
        <table border="1" class="TFtable">                
            <caption>Lista de Usuarios</caption>
            <tr style="background-color: grey">
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Codigo</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                while (result.next()) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% out.print(result.getString(1)); %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% out.print(result.getString(2)); %>
                </td>
            <tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
        </table>
        <%
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.print(e);
            }
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is a screenhot]

Comment: can post a screenshot?

Comment: by the screen shot it looks like it always returns even, try removing `style="background-color: grey"` inline style  and look if it returns yellow

Comment: It didn't work. I will post my code source

Comment: maioman I going to do an if statament inside the while loop for determine if the row either ever or odd

Comment: your tr tags are not closed

Comment: I am feel so sorry. Could I remove this post?

Comment: don't worry , it's a little distraction... can happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you're not closing `tr` tags

change this:

```
         <tr>
            <td>
                <% out.print(result.getString(1)); %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% out.print(result.getString(2)); %>
            </td>
        <tr>
```

to:

```
         <tr>
            <td>
                <% out.print(result.getString(1)); %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% out.print(result.getString(2)); %>
            </td>
           </tr>
```